# How does a many-to-many association work in rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using devise for users in my Rails application. These are my models

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    has_many :user_posts
    has_many :users, through: :user_posts
    has_many :comments
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_posts
end

class UserPost < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    belongs_to :post
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :user
end

class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :user_posts
  has_many :posts, through: :user_posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_posts
end
```

I am calling on an API for posts, and then I want my Users to create a new post and that new post should link to the user who created it. What should my controllers look like?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to make this test-driven. This is a very good habit to develop. So the first test, perhaps using Rspec and Capybara, would be to specify exactly what you said you want the app to do... a user visits the "new post" page, types text into a text box, clicks "submit" and a post is created where the post.user is the same as the user who created it.

This approach will drive the development, at first it will tell you that there is no "new post" page, so you will create the routes, controller and view for this page...

I recognize that you might be looking for an example controller, but letting the tests drive the development is, in my opinion, the best way to go.

If you don't want to do TDD, but just want to "get it done", I suggest you look at DHH's famous "blog in 15 minutes" video, it's a bit old, but the principles still apply, it's here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Gzj723LkRJY

small tip, too... you don't need all the `accepts_nested_attributes_for` statements

Comment: thank you for the advice. I checked out the youtube link, that was helpful too, appreciate it. another question, why do i not need all those accepts_nested_attributes_for statement?

Comment: You don't need ````accepts_nested_attributes_for```` in User and Post b/c there are no attributes in UserPost (except for user_id and post_id). To add a post to a user you just do ````@user,posts << @post```` and the id's will be properly assigned. You don't need ````accepts_nested_attributes_for```` in UserPost b/c you will never need to create or destroy a UserPost instance directly, so it will not be manipulating any User or Post attrs.

Answer (score 0):

There seems to be some issue in your relationship

If i put your relationship in statement then it says that `USER` can `has_many` `POST` and `POST` can `has_many` `USER` but `POST` will be create by single `USER` and it will `belongs_to` single `USER` so there no need for many-to-many relationship it should be one-to-many relationship

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, through: :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments
end
```

For your Question how your controller should look like:

```rb
class PostController < ApplicationController
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  def create
    Post.create(whitelisted_post_params.merge(user_id: current_user.id))
  end

  def whitelisted_post_params
    params.require(:post).permit(:title,:body)
  end
end
```

`current_user` is a method provided by `devise` which will return current signed
user model if user is not signed in it will return `nil`.

`before_filter` will force that user should be logged in if not it will redirect it to login page. It can be moved to `ApplicationController` that will enforce that user should login before he/she can do anything as all controller inherits from it.

For more info you can check these links: [link1](https://www.theodinproject.com/courses/ruby-on-rails/lessons/active-record-associations), [link1](https://thinkster.io/tutorials/angular-rails/associating-users-with-posts-and-comments)